# It is possible to obtain the mean of different files to make some computations with it after?

Tags: octave

I have a code to calculate the mean of the first five values of each column of a file, for then use these values as a reference point for all set. The problem is that now I need to do the same but for many files. So I will need to obtain the mean of each file to then use these values again with the originals files. I have tried in this way but I obtain an error. Thanks.

```
%%% - Loading the file of each experiment
myfiles = dir('*.lvm');     % To load every file of .lvm

for i = 1:length(myfiles)   % Loop with the number of files
    files=myfiles(i).name;
    mydata(i).files = files;
    mydata(i).T = fileread(files);
    arraymean(i) = mean(mydata(i));
end
```

The files that I need to compute are more or less like this:

```
Delta_X 3.000000    3.000000    3.000000
***End_of_Header*** 
X_Value C_P1N1  C_P1N2  C_P1N3
0.000000    -0.044945   -0.045145   -0.045705
0.000000    -0.044939   -0.045135   -0.045711
3.000000    -0.044939   -0.045132   -0.045706
6.000000    -0.044938   -0.045135   -0.045702
```

Comment: Please include the code that works, and tell us what the error is.

Comment: Hi, The problem is that I don't know what to do now. The error says 'X must be a numeric vector or matrix'. As I understand until now I have an array that keeps the name of the files but I don't understand how to compute the inside part of each file. I am sorry if the question is stupid but I don't know so much of programming. I did a program before which obtain an array with the first five values of each column and then I was able to use that array and the values of the original file but that was for one file and now with many I don't understand properly how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line results in 'myfiles' being a structure array with components that you will find defined when you type 'help dir'.  In particular, the names of all the files are contained in the structure element myfiles(i).name.  To display all the file names, type myfiles.name. So far so good. In the for loop you use 'fileread', but fileread (see help fileread) returns the character string rather than the actual values.  I have named your prototype .lvm file DinaF.lvm and I have written a very, very simple function to read the data in that file, by skipping the first three lines, then storing the following matrix, assumed to have 4 columns, in an array called T inside the function and arrayT in the main program

Here is a modified script, where a function read_lvm has been included to read your 'model' lvm file.

The '1' in the first line tells Octave that there is more to the script than just the following function: the main program has to be interpreted as well.

```
1;
function T=read_lvm(filename)
  fid = fopen (filename, "r");
  %% Skip by first three lines
  for lhead=1:3
    junk=fgetl(fid);
  endfor
  %% Read nrow lines of data, quit when file is empty
  nrow=0;
  while (! feof (fid) )
    nrow=nrow + 1;
    thisline=fscanf(fid,'%f',4);
    T(nrow,1:4)=transpose(thisline);
  endwhile
  fclose (fid);
endfunction

## main program

myfiles = dir('*.lvm');     % To load every file of .lvm

for i = 1:length(myfiles)   % Loop with the number of files
  files=myfiles(i).name;
  arrayT(i,:,:) = read_lvm(files);
  columnmean(i,1:4)=mean(arrayT(i,:,:))
end
```

Now the tabular values associated with each .lvm file are in the array arrayT and the mean for that data set is in columnmean(i,1:4). If i>1 then columnmean would be an array, with each row containing the files for each lvm file.  T

This discussion is getting to be too distant from the initial question.  I am happy to continue to help. If you want more help, close this discussion by accepting my answer (click the swish), then ask a new question with a heading like 'How to read .lvm files in Octave'.  That way you will get the insights from many more people.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it was really useful. I tried before to use load files but I got error 'load: unable to determine file format of 'tension1.lvm', as the files have text in the first rows. In the code that I wrote to read one file, I was using 'dlmread' but when I used it here I get 'dlmread: FILE argument must be a string or file id'. So, I used 'csvread' but the answer is a single value for each file not an array (It gives the mean of the 1st column of each file but no the array with the mean of all columns of each file). Do you have any suggestion?. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the first few lines of tension1.lvm?

Comment: Do you mean like this?.

Comment: Yes, please see my edited answer.  If you need more answers, please close this discussion by accepting my answer and start a new question with a title such as "How to read .lvm files in Octave"